Warning: no labels for x. Assuming order of tree$tip.label
I am using the phylANOVA() function in the R package phytools, as follows:
phylANOVA(HoloceneTree, HolDat$Category, 
          HolDat$Niche_Breadth, nsim = 1000, posthoc = T)

I keep getting the error message:
Warning: no labels for x. Assuming order of tree$tip.label.

Warning: no labels for y. Assuming order of tree$tip.label.

x and y are the categories and the continuous data, respectively. HolDat looks as follows:
structure(list(label = c("Aegotheles_novazelandiae", "Alauda_arvensis", 
"Anas_chlorotis", "Anas_platyrhynchos", "Anomalopteryx_didiformis", 
"Chen_caerulescens"), Category = c("Flightless", "True Fliers", 
"True Fliers", "True Fliers", "Flightless", "True Fliers"), biovar = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Niche_Breadth = c(5.259427983, 3.207528743, 4.208010193, 
29.52295142, 6.985928971, 32.54111922)), row.names = c("Aegotheles_novazelandiae", 
"Alauda_arvensis", "Anas_chlorotis", "Anas_platyrhynchos", "Anomalopteryx_didiformis", 
"Chen_caerulescens"), class = "data.frame")

As you can see, I have the species names as row names. I have also tried to rename the first column, with species, as "Species", "Species_Name", and "Label", and yet every time I get the same error that says that there are no labels for x and y. How do I make it so that the function can read the species names as the species labels?

HoltDat<-tibble(label = c("Aegotheles_novazelandiae", "Alauda_arvensis","Anas_chlorotis", "Anas_platyrhynchos", "Anomalopteryx_didiformis","Chen_caerulescens"), 
              Category = c("Flightless", "True Fliers","True Fliers", "True Fliers", "Flightless", "True Fliers"), 
              biovar = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
              Niche_Breadth = c(5.259427983, 3.207528743, 4.208010193,29.52295142, 6.985928971, 32.54111922),
              row.names = c("Aegotheles_novazelandiae", "Alauda_arvensis", "Anas_chlorotis", "Anas_platyrhynchos", "Anomalopteryx_didiformis", "Chen_caerulescens"))

Note that it is not an error, just a warning. If the order of the tip labels in your tree is the same as order of species in your table, it will work just fine.
To avoid problems when the order of tip labels in your tree is different, instead of your "HolDat$Category" and HolDat$Niche_Breadth, use in phylANOVA named vectors, which you can create by:
HoltDatGroups <- HoltDat$Category
names(HoltDatGroups) <- HoltDat$label
HoltDatTraits <- HoltDat$Niche_Breadth
names(HoltDatTraits) <- HoltDat$label

